# How to avoid overlapping of lines using Ext.view.View in ExtJS 7.x?

Tags: javascript, extjs7

I am using Ext.XTemplate and trying to draw lines between two icons on Ext.view.View component.

If I try to draw two lines with different colors within same two icons, then the lines are overlapped. Here I am connecting the lines by knowing x and y position of icons.

Is there any possible way to avoid such overlapping? Or is there any api in ExtJS that is used to join a line between two icons which avoid lines overlapping?

Any suggestions will be helpful...